Referential integrity constraint violation error in Spring Boot using H2 database
I have a problem with testing entities in my simple Spring Boot library api.
In this test I even manually remove every book from titles to ensure it doesn't violate anything, but the problem still occurs in line entityManager.remove(title);
    @Test
    @Transactional
    void titleAssociationTest() {
        title.getBooks().forEach(book -> {
            if (book.getLoan() != null) {
                entityManager.remove(book.getLoan());
            }
            entityManager.remove(book);
        });
        title.getBooks().clear();

        entityManager.flush();

        entityManager.remove(title);
        entityManager.flush();

        Title foundTitle = entityManager.find(Title.class, title.getId());
        assertThat(foundTitle).isNull();
    }

I receive this error message:
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK6I4NJ1U4KX1J2YOVIIM8HT8S9: PUBLIC.BOOKS FOREIGN KEY(TITLE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TITLES(ID) (CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement: 
delete from titles where id=? [23503-214]] [delete from titles where id=?]

Here is my book entity
package com.projects.library.model;

import com.projects.library.enums.BookStatus;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "title_id", nullable = false)
    private Title title;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private BookStatus status;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Loan loan;

    public Book(Title title, BookStatus status) {
        this.title = title;
        this.status = status;
    }
}

And here is title entity, where I use Cascade.ALL, so when a title is removed all books should be removed as well.
package com.projects.library.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "titles")
public class Title {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "`title`", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "author", nullable = false)
    private String author;

    @Column(name = "`year`", nullable = false)
    private int year;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "title", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    public Title(String title, String author, int year) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.year = year;
    }
}

For testing i use hibernate's H2 database with this testing profile in application-test.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Here are the full SQL logs from hibernate:
    create table books (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        status varchar(255) not null check (status in ('AVAILABLE','RENTED')),
        title_id bigint not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table books (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        status varchar(255) not null check (status in ('AVAILABLE','RENTED')),
        title_id bigint not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
2024-08-20T14:07:28.365+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    create table loans (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        borrow_date timestamp(6) not null,
        return_date timestamp(6),
        book_id bigint not null,
        user_id bigint not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table loans (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        borrow_date timestamp(6) not null,
        return_date timestamp(6),
        book_id bigint not null,
        user_id bigint not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
2024-08-20T14:07:28.371+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    create table titles (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        author varchar(255) not null,
        "title" varchar(255) not null,
        "year" integer not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table titles (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        author varchar(255) not null,
        "title" varchar(255) not null,
        "year" integer not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
2024-08-20T14:07:28.371+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    create table users (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        account_creation_date timestamp(6) not null,
        first_name varchar(255) not null,
        last_name varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table users (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        account_creation_date timestamp(6) not null,
        first_name varchar(255) not null,
        last_name varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
2024-08-20T14:07:28.379+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table if exists loans 
       drop constraint if exists UK_7t9p42ubdqp606tp4whc233lt
Hibernate: 
    alter table if exists loans 
       drop constraint if exists UK_7t9p42ubdqp606tp4whc233lt
2024-08-20T14:07:28.379+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table if exists loans 
       add constraint UK_7t9p42ubdqp606tp4whc233lt unique (book_id)
Hibernate: 
    alter table if exists loans 
       add constraint UK_7t9p42ubdqp606tp4whc233lt unique (book_id)
2024-08-20T14:07:28.379+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table if exists titles 
       drop constraint if exists UK_teg25db4y95gscy7bdb9jqmes
Hibernate: 
    alter table if exists titles 
       drop constraint if exists UK_teg25db4y95gscy7bdb9jqmes
2024-08-20T14:07:28.379+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table if exists titles 
       add constraint UK_teg25db4y95gscy7bdb9jqmes unique ("title")
Hibernate: 
    alter table if exists titles 
       add constraint UK_teg25db4y95gscy7bdb9jqmes unique ("title")
2024-08-20T14:07:28.379+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table if exists books 
       add constraint FK6i4nj1u4kx1j2yoviim8ht8s9 
       foreign key (title_id) 
       references titles
Hibernate: 
    alter table if exists books 
       add constraint FK6i4nj1u4kx1j2yoviim8ht8s9 
       foreign key (title_id) 
       references titles
2024-08-20T14:07:28.389+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table if exists loans 
       add constraint FKokwvlrv6o4i4h3le3bwhe6kie 
       foreign key (book_id) 
       references books
Hibernate: 
    alter table if exists loans 
       add constraint FKokwvlrv6o4i4h3le3bwhe6kie 
       foreign key (book_id) 
       references books
2024-08-20T14:07:28.389+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table if exists loans 
       add constraint FK6xxlcjc0rqtn5nq28vjnx5t9d 
       foreign key (user_id) 
       references users
Hibernate: 
    alter table if exists loans 
       add constraint FK6xxlcjc0rqtn5nq28vjnx5t9d 
       foreign key (user_id) 
       references users
2024-08-20T14:07:28.389+02:00  INFO 12728 --- [    Test worker] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-08-20T14:07:28.780+02:00  INFO 12728 --- [    Test worker] o.s.d.j.r.query.QueryEnhancerFactory     : Hibernate is in classpath; If applicable, HQL parser will be used.
2024-08-20T14:07:29.384+02:00  INFO 12728 --- [    Test worker] c.projects.library.model.BookTestSuite   : Started BookTestSuite in 3.519 seconds (process running for 4.796)
WARNING: A Java agent has been loaded dynamically (C:\Users\Pawe?\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.14.13\979ce25f7d3096a2e82214ba7dc972a05ce7a171\byte-buddy-agent-1.14.13.ja)
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is in use, please run with -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading to hide this warning
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is not in use, please run with -Djdk.instrument.traceUsage for more information
WARNING: Dynamic loading of agents will be disallowed by default in a future release
2024-08-20T14:07:29.884+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        titles
        (author,"title","year",id) 
    values
        (?,?,?,default)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        titles
        (author,"title","year",id) 
    values
        (?,?,?,default)
2024-08-20T14:07:29.899+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        users
        (account_creation_date,first_name,last_name,id) 
    values
        (?,?,?,default)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        users
        (account_creation_date,first_name,last_name,id) 
    values
        (?,?,?,default)
2024-08-20T14:07:29.903+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        books
        (status,title_id,id) 
    values
        (?,?,default)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        books
        (status,title_id,id) 
    values
        (?,?,default)
2024-08-20T14:07:29.906+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        loans
        (book_id,borrow_date,return_date,user_id,id) 
    values
        (?,?,?,?,default)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        loans
        (book_id,borrow_date,return_date,user_id,id) 
    values
        (?,?,?,?,default)
2024-08-20T14:07:29.924+02:00 DEBUG 12728 --- [    Test worker] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    delete 
    from
        titles 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        titles 
    where
        id=?
2024-08-20T14:07:29.931+02:00  WARN 12728 --- [    Test worker] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23503, SQLState: 23503
2024-08-20T14:07:29.931+02:00 ERROR 12728 --- [    Test worker] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Naruszenie więzów integralności: "FK6I4NJ1U4KX1J2YOVIIM8HT8S9: PUBLIC.BOOKS FOREIGN KEY(TITLE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TITLES(ID) (CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK6I4NJ1U4KX1J2YOVIIM8HT8S9: PUBLIC.BOOKS FOREIGN KEY(TITLE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.TITLES(ID) (CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
delete from titles where id=? [23503-214]


Ok the solution to the problem was simply to add on delete cascade to the constraint by adding @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) to the @OneToMany relation in entity.
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "title", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

So the constraint is being added like this:
    alter table if exists books 
       add constraint FK6i4nj1u4kx1j2yoviim8ht8s9 
       foreign key (title_id) 
       references titles 
       on delete cascade


Your constraint of FK6I4NJ1U4KX1J2YOVIIM8HT8S9 was created this way:
    alter table if exists books 
       add constraint FK6i4nj1u4kx1j2yoviim8ht8s9 
       foreign key (title_id) 
       references titles

so you have a books table which has a title_id which is a foreign key referencing titles.
So, here's the deal: whenever you intend to remove a title, all the books referencing it would become dangling and the constraint does not have an on delete cascade, so it will not clean up, leaving you with the integrity violation.
Baeldung suggests that this could help:
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)

and you have
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "title", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)

I do not think your mappedBy could possibly be a culprit, but I cannot exclude that either. Nevertheless, make sure that your database schema is in sync with the annotation. So make sure your schema is updated.
